# How can I repair my IIS? recover from IIS Crash?

Tags: iis, windows-xp

I am using Windows XP.

I've reinstalled IIS, but I still cannot see the default site in IIS and I cannot find any services running in service pool in the name of Internet Information Service.

**Why am I not able to install IIS again?**

Please help me to repair my corrupted IIS installation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Microsoft support article explaining how to remove IIS from an XP machine:

[How to remove and reinstall IIS 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;325889)

> This step-by-step article describes how to remove and reinstall Internet Information Services (IIS) versions 5.0, 5.1, and 6.0.

Answer (score -1):

Ouch. That sounds bad - I've never seen that.

Have you tried UNINSTALLING IIS? And then reinstalling it? This would be pretty much the only thing I can think of short of reinstalling the complete server.

Otherwise - please more info. Is the W3C Service still in the servicce list? Give us more information to work with.

I probably would wipe the server. I never had an server go that bonkers.

Comment: It's a Windows XP machine, not a server.